# How to filter results in a table using URL parameters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to filter results on an HTML page by having the users select multiple options through dropdowns and text boxes.

One example is filtering results within a 10 mile radius of a user.
I have all the mechanics working but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

So I have something like: 
http://slickdeals.net/deals/tech/

Where the filter options are on the left of the page, people can filter by price range, rating and so on.
So my first question is:
Using javascript how would I start tacking filter options to the URL parameters?

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
$('#FilterLocation').on('change', function () {
    window.location.replace("?lat=" + place.geometry.location.lat() + "&lng=" + place.geometry.location.lng());
});
$('#FilterPrice').on('change', function () {
    window.location.replace("?price=" + #FilterPrice.val());
});
```

And the list goes on, as you can see if my filter list has 20 options, then my javascript code just starts growing and getting messy and ugly real quick.I know there has to be a better way to do this, how?

Also second question. Once we get past the part where the URL goes into my controller, I'm using PHP.. I'm returning results by just doing WHERE queries in MySQL.

So it looks like:

```
if ($State != '' && $County != 'null' && $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County != 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal == '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal == '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State == '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal == '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal == '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County != 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal == '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif (&& $State == '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State == '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County != 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County == 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } elseif ($State != '' && $County != 'null' &&  $isOnlineDeal != '') {
                $query = "select * from posts where ...";
            } else {
                $query = "select * from posts";
            }
```

As you can see, I'm just doing a bunch of elseif's to check if variables are not empty and doing queries based on that. Once my filter options start getting bigger, this also grows.

The specific data has been altered and isn't important, what I'm really trying to find out is:
1. What's the best way to tack on url params to the url with javascript/jquery.
2. Without having messy code, how do I filter those URL params in MySQL.

Comment: Might be worth separating into two questions?

Comment: You need to more-intuitively extract data from the selections by using classes. You should only need one jQuery to get all you need from the selection. Also, your php needs to be more intuitive. You should not need all the `if/else` you have.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question:
Just get everything from the form as JSON using something like

```
json = {}
$('input[data-send="true"]').forEach(function() { //example selector
    key = $(this).getattr("name");
    value = $(this).val();
    json[key] = value;
});
```

then parse it into URI using something like

```
var uri = Object.keys(json).map(function(key){ 
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(json[key])
}).join('&');
```

You can easily reverse the process to load the values back in.

As for the PHP cleanup - you could think about writing some kind of handler, where there would be different listeners for every piece of URI... But that would be an overkill: maybe `switch` using an `enum`? Haven't written a lot of PHP code in the last 3 years tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think your best bet is using ajax *(in this case jQuery)* for the form, then a class to handle your php. Here is a basic example *(snippit from a class I use, but modified for this purpose)*. This is not something to just copy and paste, it's to give you an idea of what may be required:

Not sure if you are using `mysqli` or `PDO`, this class uses `PDO`:

**/classes/Database.php**

```
<?php
class   Database
    {
        private $con,
                $query,
                $bind,
                $sql;
        private static  $singleton;

        public  function __construct()
            {
                // Return self for lower-resourse reuse
                if(empty(self::$singleton))
                    self::$singleton    =   $this->connection();
            }
        /*
        ** @description This will connect to your database, db creds requried
        */
        public  function connection($host = 'localhost',$database = 'database',$username = 'root',$password = '')
            {
                // Some settings for the PDO connection
                $settings   =   array(  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false);
                // Saves the connection and returns it                  
                $this->con  =   new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password,$settings);

                return $this->con;
            }
        /*
        ** @description creates the values string with bind array
        */
        public  function getSelectStr($array)
            {
                if(!is_array($array))
                    return;

                $this->sql  =   array();

                $i  =   0;
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $aKey               =   ":{$i}";
                    $this->bind[$aKey]  =   $value;
                    $this->sql[]        =   "`{$key}` = {$aKey}";
                    $i++;
                }

                return (!empty($this->sql))? ' WHERE '.implode(" and ",$this->sql) : '';
            }
        /*
        ** @description This queries the database
        */
        public  function query($sql,$bind = false)
            {
                $this->bind =   false;
                try {
                    if(empty($bind)) {
                        $this->query    =   self::$singleton->query($sql);
                    }
                    else {
                        foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                            $key                =   trim($key,':');
                            $bkey               =   ":{$key}";
                            $this->bind[$bkey]  =   $value;
                        }

                        $this->query    =   self::$singleton->prepare($sql);
                        $this->query->execute($this->bind);
                    }
                }
                catch (PDOException $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $this;
            }
        /*
        ** @description This fetches results if a select query sent
        */
        public  function getResults()
            {
                while($results = $this->query->fetch()) {
                    $row[]  =   $results;
                }

                return (!empty($row))? $row : 0;
            }
        /*
        ** @description This will retrieve the bind array
        */
        public  function getBind()
            {
                return $this->bind;
            }
    }
```

This is the form plus the spot where your content will drop:

**/index.php**

```
<form method="post">
    <select class="dynamic" name="option1">
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <select class="dynamic" name="option2">
        <option value="one one">One</option>
        <option value="two two">Two</option>
        <option value="three three">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
<!-- Here is where content will populate on ajax response -->
<div id="dropspot"></div>
```

jQuery to process the `onchange` and ajax

**/index.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // On change of any class named "dynamic"
    $(this).on('change','.dynamic', function () {
        // Get the form
        var thisForm    =   $(this).parents('form');
        // Get data from form
        var formData    =   thisForm.serialize();
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            // Use this page url to process the ajax
            url: '/processor.php',
            // Send via $_POST
            type: 'post',
            // Send the form data
            data: formData,
            // On success write the response to the container
            success: function(response) {
                $('#dropspot').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is your page that creates the html for the main content:

**/processor.php**

```
<?php
// This is the page labeled "processor.php" in the ajax script
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    require(__DIR__.'/classes/Database.php');
    // Create new database instance
    $con        =   new Database();
    // Generate a string and bind array from post
    $qStr       =   $con->getSelectStr($_POST);
    // Create the statement
    echo
    $statement  =   "SELECT * from `posts`{$qStr}";
    // Get the bind array
    $bind       =   $con->getBind();
    print_r($bind);
    // Get the results
    $results    =   $con->query($statement,$bind)->getResults();
    print_r($results);
    exit;
}
?>
```

The results from the php page will be:

```
SELECT * from `posts` WHERE `option1` = :0 and `option2` = :1

Array
(
    [:0] => three
    [:1] => three three
)
```